# python request login to website

Tags: python

I am learning about how to login to websites with `python` and `requests` and went through a number of different posts on stackoverflow and videos on youtube on what is required and how to do it.

I found that the below information is being sent through the `form` when I clicked submit on the browser. *I went to the developer tools under network and took a look at the headers*

[image: form response when submitting on website]

**What I can tell**

What I can tell is that on the login page itself, they only ask for `username` and `password` of which the below code is the `html` extract.

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="T8NxfsxCHqUPzdvmM++VIpipimDyjsLHkg4Oz3Yuouk="></div>
<ul class="sic_loginFailed">
    <li>
      <label for="sic_login_header_username">Username</label>
      <input id="sic_login_header_username" name="name" type="text" class="sic_formText">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="sic_login_header_password">Password</label>
      <input id="sic_login_header_password" name="password" type="password" class="sic_formText">
    </li>
    <li class="sic_remember">
      <input id="sic_login_header_remember" name="remember" type="checkbox">
      <label for="sic_login_header_remember">Remember my login.</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" 
value="https://www.shareinvestor.com/sg">



      <input id="sic_login_submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="sic_greenInputButton">
    </li>
  </ul>
```

So that means that `authenticity token` and `password_m` is auto generated by the website? Note: I have a feeling `password_m` is auto assigned to me when I created my account. But the token is auto generated at every login.

**My question**

I wrote the below code based on what I know and what I have researched, but I am still unable to log into the website.

```
url = "https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html"  # This is the main URL login page

login_data = {'name': 'test_user',
              'password': 'test_password',
              'password_m': '5d93ceb70e2bf5daa84ec3d0cd2c731a',
              'remember': True,
              'redirect': 'https://www.shareinvestor.com/sg'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    a = s.get(url).text
    b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml')
    c = b.findAll('input', type='hidden')  # This is to draw out the token. I tried searching for it in the cookies previously, but failed badly.... 
    for i in c:
        login_data[i['name']] = i['value']

    # I use the this url for the response because as per the `Headers` in the picture above, it says that this is the request URL that the form is submitting to. 
    response = requests.post('https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/do_login.html?use_https=1', data=login_data)
    response = requests.get('https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/edit_profile.html', cookies=response.cookies)

    print(response.text)
```

If you have read this far, I would really appreciate if you could shed some light on what I am doing right or wrong in trying to login to the website, and persist the login.

Comment: Use the session while making requests. `s.post` and `s.get` instead of last two requests

Comment: Thanks @AndrewCherevatkin. You are right. I should be using `s.post / s.get` instead of requests. This solves my issue. I was so close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what Andrew Cherevatkin has mentioned, I should be using `s.post` and `s.get` instead of requests. By using `requests.post` and `requests.get` I lose everything that I collected through the`session()`